# How to provide an object using hilt in background thread with coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I want to provide a realm object in the background thread like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabaseScope(): CoroutineScope = GlobalScope + Dispatchers.IO

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabaseQueue(): ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher =
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGetRealmConfig(accountService: AccountService): GetRealmConfig =
        GetRealmConfig(accountService)

    @Provides
    fun provideRealmConfig(
        getRealmConfig: GetRealmConfig,
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        accountService: AccountService
    ): RealmConfigImpl = RealmConfigImpl(getRealmConfig, accountService, context)


    @Provides
    fun provideRealmCreator(
        realmConfigImpl: RealmConfigImpl,
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        queue: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher
    ): Realm {
        return RealmCreator(realmConfigImpl, scope, queue).createRealmObject()!!
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserDatabase(
        realm: Realm,
        databaseScope: CoroutineScope,
        databaseQueue: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher
    ): UserDataStorage = UserDataStorageImpl(realm, databaseScope, databaseQueue)
}
```

and this is RealmCreator class that creates the object in the background thread:

```
class RealmCreator @Inject constructor(
    val realmConfigImpl: RealmConfigImpl,
    val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    val executorCoroutineDispatcher: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher
) {
    var realm: Realm? = null
    fun createRealmObject(): Realm? {

        coroutineScope.launch(executorCoroutineDispatcher) {
            try {
                realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfigImpl.realmConfiguration!!)
                countDownLatch.countDown()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()

            }
        }

        return realm
    }
}
```

when I want to create a Realm object it returns null because this process is in a background thread.
How can I create this object in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Apart from your intention of realm object creation in the background, your code is an example of Unstructured Concurrency. You're passing `CoroutineScope` in the constructor. You need to use `coroutineScope()` as a global suspend function that creates a new `CoroutineScope` under the hood and then executes the suspend function you pass with it in the body, and wait for it (and all its children) to complete before returning. It is a suspend function so you cannot call it outside of a coroutine like `createRealmObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use **Provider** in dagger. Refer to this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/improving-android-startup-initializing-dagger-async-f8193b48f834).